# Upload from embedded UIWebView using ink filepicker

Tags: ios, file-upload, uiwebview, filepicker.io

I have a website that is using ink's filepicker javascript lib to upload photos. It works in browsers on both desktop and mobile, the difference is on iOS it will open up a separate tab and upload from there and return to parent tab once upload is done, but on desktop it just opens in a modal view.

Now I am embedding a UIWebView in an app so there is no tabs. The page where upload button is will be replaced by the filepicker uploader, and I was expecting it to preserve the state of it's parent page, but somehow it won't. I am unable to upload even though the same upload button works in the same simulator in browser. Do I have to use the filepicker iOS library for this kind of in-app upload? Are there any work-arounds? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  Is there any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found any. I'm using the native library and then evaluate javascript on the webview to inject the filepicker remote url back onto the form. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with embedding my JavaScript/Filepicker based site within my native iOS app in UIWebView.
I contacted Filepicker.io dev support and here is their statement:

"unfortunately the way it looks currently is that the limitations of UIWebView prohibits cross-window communication, because as you're seeing the state of the parent window is not saved."

So, I am going to have to use native Filepicker library as well on iOS.